# for loop changes array's value in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, graph

I have a graph representation and I want to make an array to keep indegrees.

Here a small test:

```
int main()
{
    Graph g1(5);
    g1.addEdge(1, 1);
    g1.addEdge(1, 2);
    g1.addEdge(1, 3);
    g1.addEdge(2, 3);
    g1.addEdge(3, 1);
    g1.addEdge(3, 2);
    g1.addEdge(3, 5);
    g1.addEdge(5, 4);

    cout<<g1.array[0]<<endl;
    cout<<g1.array[1]<<endl;
    cout<<g1.array[2]<<endl;
    cout<<g1.array[3]<<endl;
    cout<<g1.array[4]<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < g1.V ; i++) {
        cout<<g1.array[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<g1.array[4]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
values
2
2
2
1
1
entering for loop
2
2
2
1
4              <<< 1 is expected for the last item
loop ended
5              <<< 1 is still expected for last item - but why isn't it 4 anymore?
```

Why `g1.array[4]` is changing ?

It looks like my array's last value has changed in for loop. I could not find what the wrong is.

Here my class definition:

```
class Graph
{
    //int V; // No. of vertices
    list<int> *adj; // A dynamic array of adjacency lists
    // A Recursive DFS based function used by SCC()
    void SCCUtil(int u, int disc[], int low[],
                 stack<int> *st, bool stackMember[]);
    void topologicalSortUtil(int v, bool visited[], stack<int> &Stack);

public:
    int V;
    int array [];
    Graph(int V); // Constructor
    void addEdge(int v, int w); // function to add an edge to graph
    void SCC(); // prints strongly connected components
    void topologicalSort();

};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    array[V];
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v-1].push_back(w-1);
    array[w-1]++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the Graph ?  There's something wrong with the size of the array.

Comment: I see a couple of close votes because there wouldn't be an MCVE.  But since the edit of the question, everything needed to reproduce the error is here !

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your array.  In fact, in C++ an array must be of fixed size and they do not grow dynamically. So your code has undefined behavior.

To solve this, replace in `Graph` your array with a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
vector<int> array;   //<==== better definition than in array[];
```

In the constructor you can then resize it as you wanted:

```
array.resize(V);   //<===== instead of array[V] which only accesses a non existing element
```

This is [sufficient to make your code work](https://ideone.com/rv9DHu) :-)

Another approach could be to use a pointer to an array, but this requires allocation and deallocation of memory and is very error prone.  So better stick to the vector.

***Not related:*** giving direct access to the array/vector is not a good encapsulation. So once everything works, consider making it private and use a getter to access the elements and prevent unauthorised change.